# how to do databinding between XML file using C# in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dataset, datasource

I have a xml file which structure is given below

```
<root>
  <contact name="abc">
    <name>Apurv Kumar</name>
    <email>apurva3633a@gmail.com</email>
    <EmpID>JSE040</EmpID>
  </contact>
</root
```

Now I want two way binding in C#.net between the following three Winforms textboxes with the above said xml file nodes so that whatever I will change at run time in the text boxes it will reflect on the corresponding node values of the above xml file and will update the xml file dynamically.

```
textBox1.text=name
textBox2.text=email
textBox3.text=EmpID
```

I am very new to this Winforms world, Please anybody suggest me in creating dataset or a datasource which will handle all this Binding issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We have datagridview and listview components in winforms world, meet them and choose one :)

Answer (score 6):

Following code is for binding text box to your dataset,

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); //Private Variable class level
        //write this code on form load
        dataset ds = new dataset();
        ds.readxml("XML File Path of yours");

        bs.DataSource = ds;
        bs.DataMember = ds.table[0].tablename;

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("FirstName", bs, "Table Name");
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("FirstName", bs, "Table Name");
```

Use class level BindingSource  Instance and attach it to all your text boxes, also you can do it on design time.

Follow [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/527579-setting-bindingsource-data-types-xml-data-source) link for more on binding or creating dataset from XML.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply, this is exactly what I need but as I am very new to this field so I am not able to make it in coding so can you please share a sample application for this so that I am able to know how to go for it. Thanks again for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

In worst case you can do i this by ontextchanged event else provide one submit button.

```
 private void OnNameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument sampleDoc = new XmlDocument();
         sampleDoc.Load(@"sample.xml");
        sampleDoc.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText = textBox1.Text;
        sampleDoc.Save(@"sample.xml");
    }

    private void OnEmailChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument sampleDoc = new XmlDocument();
         sampleDoc.Load(@"sample.xml");           
        sampleDoc.GetElementsByTagName("email")[0].InnerText = textBox2.Text;
       sampleDoc.Save(@"sample.xml");

    }

    private void OEmpIdChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument sampleDoc = new XmlDocument();
        sampleDoc.Load(@"sample.xml");

        sampleDoc.GetElementsByTagName("EmpID")[0].InnerText = textBox3.Text;
        sampleDoc.Save(@"sample.xml");           
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Can you please tell me how to perform this by creating DataSet because while I'll change the xml nodes names then I have to change the same inside the code also and I think it is little painful to make changes in several places instead doing in one place

Comment: Create the constants for the each the nodename and place in the single class.

Comment: If you don't mind then can you please share a sample application here, I am facing lot of issues like Dynamically updating the fields value and inserting new node into the xml file etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'd have a look at.  [linq-to-xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

That should make databinding simple enough.

Comment: -1 perhaps a simple example would help, the link you've provided doesn't answer the question at all.